# colors not changing on pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, color-scheme

Installed PyCharm 2016.2. Playing with the color schemes.
I've noticed some colors are not the same from what I remember on previous PC.
[image]

I remember all the parameters to be types of oranges, while strings to be yellow or green. After playing with all the schemes, I realized that although most of the colors change, those remain the same.

Twilight
[image]

Default
[image]

Github
[image]

I even played with custom schemes and tried to change it on the General and specific language setting but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue, but had two projects running side by side, one yellow, other dark cyan, as in your case. The only difference was Python 2 vs Python 3...

Solution:

1. Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Python
2. Then choose "String (bytes)" and "String (Unicode)" - defaults are of different color!

Comment: This was, in fact, the answer. I solved a few months ago, but since forgetting to answer it myself, I'll mark yours as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two settings for colors:

- One in `Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance > Theme` (the one you seem to change)
- One in `Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts`, which seems to be the one you're looking for.

From your description, i'd guess you're looking for the 'Darcula' scheme.

Comment: Running Dracula for the appearance (Only dark one there) and Monokai editor color. Problem remains.